# Alternatives to Scipy in Global optimization

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, minimization

I'm trying to find a global minimum of a multivariate function (`ndim = 9`). The function has very narrow bottoms and a slight change to the X causes the output value to rise quite quickly. I tried various scipy methods, like `differential_evolution`, `basin_hopping`, `dual_annealing`, `shgo`. They perform quite well, but I still end up in the local minimum rather than the absolute global minimum.

What other packages/algorithms would you suggest trying?

Comment: This is off topic due to seeking generic recommendations,

Answer (score 1):

You could try [nlopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I've used it a few times, mostly for local optimization and mostly in C++ (it also has Python bindings), but it looks like it also might have some global optimization algorithms that SciPy doesn't. I'm not sure if it will be better, but perhaps worth a shot. Good luck!